# How to retrieve an image stored in folder and SQL using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to update an image saved into a directory. I also saved the filename into MySQL. Saving images is working using the `move_uploaded_file()`. But it seems that there is no way to fetch the filename from database into `<input type="file">`. So what do you think is the best way to let my users know that they are editing the image since I can't pass a value into an `input:file` tag. How could I show the users the image they are trying editing.

[image: product list with edit button]

[image: edit product page]

[[image: database3]

Comment: `it seems that there is no way to fetch the filename from database into <input type="file">`....no there isn't. But why would you want to? `<input type="file">` is for **inputting** files. If you want to display a file in a web page, use an `<img>`.

Comment: Onc ethe filename and path are stored in the database you would not use `input type='file'` to edit anything, only to replace the image with another image in which case when the new image is selected and the form POSTed you already know the ID of the record that stored the image originally so update that record.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius so do you think I should leave the edit product page as it is, not displaying the image they are editing? and just replace the old uploaded file with the new one?

Comment: Unless you actually allow the user to edit the image ( as one would in photoshop or similar ) then you are not really editing the image. You can easily show the image and that can be useful if, for example, the user wants to add a description of the image...

Comment: You can use some cunning CSS position of elements and javascript to give the illusion that the `file` input has the original file re-loaded in the edit page.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes. all I'm trying to say about _updating the images_ is if the admin wants to replace or probably add new images for a particular productID.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the image downloaded into the users' computers, then edited, then re-uploaded replacing the existing image.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment - you could use a littler trickery to give the illusion that the `file input` has the image name already loaded using css and javascript. The following example is very quickly cobbled together (tested in Chrome only ) and roughly approximates the impression that the filename is pre-selected (apart from text in red to highlight things here)

```
<?php
    $filename='default.jpg'; // this would be from database select query...
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #product{
                width:200px;
                height:2rem;
                display:inline-block;
                position:absolute;
                left:6rem;
                background:white;
                color:red;
                font-weight:bold;
                z-index:2;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            input[type='file']{
                height:2rem;
                float:left;
                clear:none;
                z-index:1;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <div id='container'>
                <span id='product'><?=$filename;?></span>
                <input type='file' name='product' />
            </div>
        </form>
        <script>
            let oInput=document.querySelector('input[type="file"][name="product"]');
            let oSpan=document.getElementById('product');
            
            oSpan.addEventListener('click',e=>{e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
                oInput.click();
            });
            
            oInput.addEventListener('change',e=>{
                oSpan.parentNode.removeChild(oSpan);
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
let oInput=document.querySelector('input[type="file"][name="product"]');
let oSpan=document.getElementById('product');

if( oSpan ){
    oSpan.addEventListener('click',e=>{e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
      oInput.click();
    });
}

oInput.addEventListener('change',e=>{
  if( oSpan )oSpan.parentNode.removeChild(oSpan);
})
```

```css
#product{
  width:200px;
  height:2rem;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  left:5.75rem;
  background:white;
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
  z-index:2;
  cursor:pointer;
}
input[type='file']{
  height:2rem;
  float:left;
  clear:none;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<form method='post'>
  <div id='container'>
    <span id='product'>default.jpg</span>
    <input type='file' name='product' />
  </div>
</form>
```